# Uploading addon in JIRA

Tags: cloud, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-connect

As instructed here,

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/developing/cloud-installation.html

I added my plugin into atlassian marketplace. Created tokens with addon in private mode. When I upload addon using the created token, I get the error:

"The add-on failed to install. Please try again later or contact the add-on vendor."

By the way descriptor is also valid, when I tested with descriptor validation. But also I cannot upload addon. Is there any other process to get completed.

I had surfed in internet about this issue, where I came to know that the same question has been raised here:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Error-Adding-Addon/qaq-p/540404

But the answer here did not help us, can I get a clear solution for the issue. What's the reason for the issue, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things -
First of all check Audit log for any specific error.

Two cents from my end -

1. Make sure all URLs in descriptor are secure i.e https and certificates are not self signed
2. Make sure all life cycle URLS are up and running. Your app that jira addon talks to is working.